# How to install ruby 2.3.1 on windows 8 with Cygwin64 Terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, cygwin, rvm

I am trying to install ruby 2.3.1 on windows 8.1(64) with rvm on cygin, using the following commands:

`gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

`rvm install ruby-2.3.1` after that, I get this error:

```
ruby-2.3.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.3.1..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: cygwin/unknown/x86_64/ruby-2.3.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more 
information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for cygwin.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/mypc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1, this may 
take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.1 - #downloading ruby-2.3.1, this may take a while depending on 
your connection...
ruby-2.3.1 - #extracting ruby-2.3.1 to /home/mypc/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.1....
ruby-2.3.1 - #applying patch 
/home/mypc/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.3.1/fix_resolv_kernel32_dll.patch.
ruby-2.3.1 - 
#configuring..........................................................
ruby-2.3.1 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.3.1 - #compiling...........
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /home/mypc/.rvm/log/1501370385_ruby-2.3.1/make.log
rb_str_new_static((str), (long)strlen(str)) : \
                                    ^
ruby.c:417:29: erreur : request for member ‘dli_fname’ in something not a 
structure or union
fname = rb_str_new_cstr(dli.dli_fname);
                         ^
./include/ruby/intern.h:807:18: note : in definition of macro 
‘rb_str_new_cstr’
  rb_str_new_cstr(str);   \
                   ^

ruby.c:402:1: attention : ‘dladdr_path’ defined but not used [-Wunused-
function]
dladdr_path(const void* addr)
^
```

I reloaded the rvm dependencies with `rvm requirements`, but I still have the same message error, even after doing [this](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3706#issuecomment-248158211).

Comment: cygwin ruby package  2.3.3 is available why you need to go backward ?

Comment: I want to install a devlopement environement for an open source project which require to install ruby 2.3.1.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would meet your needs, but you could try just installing the native Windows version of Ruby 2.3.1 with rubyinstaller and then use it from MSYS2 instead of cygwin. I've had good luck developing and testing Ruby projects on Windows using MSYS2 and the mintty terminal. I haven't tried installing Ruby via rvm in MSYS2, but that might work also.

Comment: Thank you @jholtrop, today I installed ruby 2.3.3 following this medium post, and I will delete the ruby version line in the Gemfile. That's my work arround until I find a way to install ruby 2.3.1.

Comment: https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/how-to-install-rubyonrails-on-windows-7-8-10-complete-tutorial-2017-fc95720ee059